# Multiple Profile forms with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm creating an application with Symfony 2 and the FOSUserBundle. I have my own UserBundle  configured correctly. My User Entity has  a lot of attributes of different categories (For example location settings, personal settings, ...) so I want to make different forms for each category so I can show each setting category on a different page.

I know how to make a custom profile form (it's in the FOSUserBundle Documentation), I already made multiple FormTypes and an additional controller but I just can't get it populated with the current user data. I tried the following

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
// Try 1
$form = $this->createForm(new InnerCharacteristicsType());  
// Try 2
$form = $this->createForm(new InnerCharacteristicsType($user));
// Try 3
$form = $this->createForm(new InnerCharacteristicsType(), $user);
// Try 4
$form = $this->createForm(new InnerCharacteristicsType(), array('user' => $user);

return $this->render('AcmeUserBundle:EditProfile:inner.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

(Of course, I didn't try them at the same time)

I also tried to make the new forms a service by adding my InnerCharacteristics Form to the services.yml but I couldn't find any documentation on this. The profile.xml in the FOSUserBundle itself also isn't very helpful because I couldn't find where the parameters are pointing at. Also the XML to YAML conversion isn't very easy since the documentation about this is not very helpful (this is needed because the FOSUserBundle configuration is in XML and my UserBundle configuration in YAML).

This is what i have in my services.yml now:

```
acme_user.inner_characteristics_profile.form:
  class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
  factory_service: form.factory
  factory_method: createNamed
```

I hope someone can give me some pointers where to go next.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to create the form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new InnerCharacteristicsType(), $user);
```

Inside your form you should do something like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // Add fields
    $builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name:'));
}
```

This should load up the `name` property from the `user` object inside your form. Is the form successfully loaded?